# AnkhSVN with Visual Studio Express 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express, ankhsvn

Trying to use [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) with Visual Studio Express 2015.  We downloaded the MSI from the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/E721D830-7664-4E02-8D03-933C3F1477F2), and installed it.  It doesn't appear in the Installed Extensions in VS 2015, nor is it listed as an available source control provider in Tools -> Options -> Source Control.

The "AnkhSVN" folder wasn't in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\`, so I tried copying that folder from another computer that has VS 2015 Enterprise.  But still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions do not support plug-ins. Use Community Edition if you meet the licensing requirements or purchase Visual Studio Professional.

- [Differences between Visual Studio Community Edition and Express Editions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onecode/2014/11/12/differences-between-visual-studio-community-edition-and-express-editions/)
- [Why Visual Studio Express Won't Allow Extensions](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx)